# keyboard is not responding when My grub is open

Tags: grub2

When I open my pc grub is showing but I cannot select any system that I want because my keyboard is not working when my grub is open .. I tried with another keyboard but it reponse but my keyboard is not responding when grub is showing but after that it it automatically open ubuntu and I after that i can use my keyboard .

Answer (score 2):

It is the fast boot, disable it via bios and all will works wells, to perform a start without the fast boot unplug the power cord from power supply for a couple of seconds (5-10 should be enough)

Comment: Should I unpluged all the times ??? Cause this is so painfull

Comment: And from where I should disable fast boot ?? I m using dual boot one is ububtu and one is windows 10 ..

Comment: Not all the time, in the bios settings have the fastboot